# How do I stop thunar trying auto-mount a partition

Tags: automounting, thunar

When I plug in **SIPOD**, *my pet ipod*, thunar tries to auto-mount **two** partitions instead of **one**.

This annoying pop-up is starting to kill me:

[image]

This is what `/dev/sde` looks like:

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/sde*
/dev/sde:  x86 boot sector, code offset 0x58, OEM-ID "MSDOS5.0", Bytes/sector 2048, sectors/cluster 8, reserved sectors 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads 255, sectors 39075371 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 0, infoSector 0, Backup boot sector 0, reserved3 0x50000, physical drive 0x5, serial number 0xa88b3652, label: "       iPod"
/dev/sde1: data
/dev/sde2: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x3c, OEM-ID "*UOKJIHC" cached by Windows 9M, Bytes/sector 2048, sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads 255, hidden sectors 64260, sectors 39011108 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 9522, reserved3 0x1000000, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x58dd9832, label: "SIPOD      "
```

Is there a way to tell thunar to completely ignore `/dev/sde1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't belive that the thunar automount is configurable to ignore special devices (I'm not for 100% sure...).

Anyway in my point of view, mounting filesystems is not the job of an application, it should be the job of the operating system.

You could disable thunars automount feature and use [udev](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Input%20Configuration%20with%20udev%20%28Ubuntu%2010.04%29) and [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs).

With udev rules you can recoginze your devices and define how to handle it.